# Best Data Containers(s) to Fit My Requirements?

Tags: c++11

I am writing a custom 3D model export/importer, and right now I'm working on the exporter for my custom file type. Basically, the format consists of the @ symbol + a keyword to denote sections, for example:

```
@version(1.0)
@name("test")
@source("src/test.model")

@mesh
  @vertices(v34,4,5512 v23,56,75)
  @indices(i0, 1, 2 i3, 4, 5)
@end
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to to choose a container(vector, list, deque, map, etc.) for this task. Here are my specifications:

1. The keywords (@mesh, @animation, etc.) will NEVER change, so I'm not too concerned about insertion/removal performance.
2. There are three different "tiers" of keywords: global, object, and attribute, so I will require 3 different sections in the container to store each.
3. When reading a keyword from a file I will need to check it against the container to make sure it is a valid keyword, so I will be doing a lot of searches. Therefore, I would prefer a container that could perform searches faster then O(n).

With these requirements in mind, I still can't think of a container that would allow me to store all three tiers of keywords without having to have three seperate containers (wasteful). Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Looking at this I guess you probably have classes/structures which are representing the mesh and also for vertices and indices. I would use a `std::unordered_map` with a `boost::variant` as value type and `std::string` as key. But if there are no custom keys and all are known to the program I would even go for a mapping of the keywords to `enum class`

Comment: @Vinzenz: Correct. The data is gathered through a model loading library and optimized, then written to this file. Performance isn't a concern when writing this file because it isn't done at runtime. Loading this file, however, is...

Comment: So I map all of them to their own enum class, or the same one? What do I do after I "map" them?

Comment: Ok I just see that I misunderstood for what you need the container. I was looking at the file and thought you're trying to map this. I should have read the question properly, my bad sorry. I hope that I now get it. Forget about my first comment ;) I will post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum GlobalKeywords {
    GK_FIRST = 0,
    GK_VERSION = GK_FIRST,
    GK_NAME,
    // .... more here
    GK_COUNT // Always last one
};
static char const * const GLOBAL_KEYWORD_STRINGS[GK_COUNT] = {
    "version", "name" //...
};

enum ObjectKeywords {
    OK_FIRST,
    OK_MESH = OK_FIRST,
    // .... more here
    OK_COUNT // Always last one
};

static char const * const OBJECT_KEYWORD_STRINGS[OK_COUNT] = {
    "mesh" //...
};

enum AttributeKeywords {
    AK_FIRST = 0,
    AK_VERTICES = AK_FIRST,
    AK_INDICES,
    //...
    AK_COUNT
};
static char const * const ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD_STRINGS[AK_COUNT] = {
    "vertices", "indices" //...
};

enum class KeywordCategory {
    KC_GLOBAL,
    KC_OBJECT,
    KC_ATTRIBUTE
};
```

Type `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<Keywordcategory, std::uint32_t>> mapping;`

Insertion:

```
for(std::uint32_t i = GK_FIRST; i < GK_COUNT; ++i) 
{
    mapping[GLOBAL_KEYWORD_STRINGS[i]] = std::make_pair(KC_GLOBAL, i);
}

for(unsigned i = OK_FIRST; i < OK_COUNT; ++i) 
{
    mapping[OBJECT_KEYWORD_STRINGS[i]] = std::make_pair(KC_OBJECT, i);
}

for(unsigned i = AK_FIRST; i < AK_COUNT; ++i) 
{
    mapping[ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD_STRINGS[i]] = std::make_pair(KC_ATTRIBUTE, i);
}
```

Now you have a mapping object with a O(1) lookup and it tells you what Category it is and what exact entry as a numeric representation.

HTH,

Comment: Interesting. I will implement this in the morning, thank you!